# Uploading a Website

Tags: mysql, security, codeigniter, web, web-hosting

This is my first time building a website and using CodeIgniter for a school project. I was wondering whether you have any tips on uploading CI to a free web host , my database, free webhosting and basic security tips.

Can I just upload the entire CI folder? Or do I have to upload individual files (God no!)? What are my options?

What about my MySQL database - do I just upload my mysqldump to the webhost?

Also, can you recommend a good free webhost. I was thinking about 000webhost.

Any basic tips on security would also be appreciated (I've implemented many of the form_validation rules like xss_clean for starters)

Any other suggestions will be more than welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used 000webhost.com long time ago and remembered having minor inconvenient here and there (i.e.: slow connection, server unreachable sometime). I don't have any suggestion on a good free webhost because in most situation the words "good" and "free webhost" do not belong in the same sentence. You get what you paid for.

Now, onto the uploading itself.

1. You need to upload the entire CI folder and your app as well

   - You can either zip them all and extract the zip if you have shell access to the server
   - You can use FTP to upload all files at once
2. MySQL DB: if you have SQL scripts, you can execute them in phpMyAdmin interface if the web host provider gives you access to it. Please read phpMyAdmin documentation for ways to upload your MySQL data.

In terms of security:

- http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/index.html
- http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/security.html
- Sanitize user input if you're using SQL expression directly
- If you are using CI ORM/database library, make sure you keep yourself up to date to any security issues by checking CI mailing-list, IRC, or whichever the preferred communication channel the CI people use.
- For simplicity, avoid HTML tags (as a user) input, treat them as literal

Comment: +1. Thanks Edwin. I will check out those links and thanks for the great advice

Answer (score 2):

Instead of uploading individual files make the entire directory into a zip folder (or any compressed folder) to save bandwidth and time.

Also most webhosts will have an uploader, but im not sure about free hosts supporting database services, you would have to look into that.

Comment: +1 Thanks for your advice Grue. I'll look out for that uploader or zip it when I'm ready.

Comment: From my experiance most companies try to get you to purchase a more expensive package for more databases, so I would assume that free hosts would ask you to pay for any databases, but it will probably vary.

As for securit

Comment: I glanced at 000webhost a few weeks ago and if I recall correctly, mysql is included in the free package, i'll have to double check. But I know what you mean by the upselling - GoDaddy is sickening with it!